# Finding the limit of an integral

Tags: integration, limits, summation

Evaluate $$\displaystyle\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{j!} \left(\ln \left(\frac{A}{x}\right)\right)^{j}dx$$

Comment: Is the integration with respect to $x$?

Comment: Oops..yes..wrt x

Comment: Are both $a$ and $A$ the same?

Comment: Nope they are not same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take $j=n$, as an integer.

Using IBP, we may show that the integral would be
\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{n!} \left(\ln \left(\frac{A}{x}\right)\right)^{n}dx &= a\, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\left(\ln{\frac{A}{a}}\right)^k}{k!} \\
    \implies   \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{n!} \left(\ln \left(\frac{A}{x}\right)\right)^{n}dx &= a\, e^{\ln{(A/a)}} \\
   &= a\cdot \frac{A}{a} \\
   &= A
\end{align*}